# How to remove singularit​ies/discon​tinuities on 3D plots in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plotting, mathematica

I want to plot some functions f(x,y) including singularities.
For example;
f(x,y)=tan(x-y)

- In Matlab, when I run the following code

`syms x y; func=@(x,y)  tan(x-y); fsurf(@(x,y) func(x,y), [-4 2 -1 1]);`

I get

[image]

- In Mathematica, when I plot the same function, I can remove the discontinuities using Exclusions -> "Singularities"

[image]

**My question:** In MATLAB,  how to remove vertical asymptote lines in Matlab's figure like Mathematica?

-How to find the asymptote lines in Matlab. After finding the asymptote, maybe we make it invisible in the plot.

Comment: Did you try clipping the z value in Matlab to e.g. (staying with your Mathematica example) [-5, 5] ? If you need it for a general case, you could try to clip the values to some multiplicity of the mean value(assuming the mean is not too corrupted).

Comment: That will not help because MATLAB interpolates across the discontinuity. The singularities should be detected (as in Mathematica) and the numerical data could be plotted piecewise.

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB doesn’t plot where there are NaNs, so you can replace some of your data with NaNs to make a clean jump.

I don’t know which is a bigger lie, a clean jump or a strange wiggle. That’s up to your eye and values.